# Multivariate Rational Functions

Tags: polynomials, integers, rational-functions

Let $P(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, $Q(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ be multivariate polynomials with integer coefficients. Assume that for all $(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $Q(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \neq 0$ we have:
$$\frac{P(x_1,\cdots,x_n)}{Q(x_1,\cdots,x_n)} \in \mathbb{Z}$$Does it necessarily follow that there exists a multivariate polynomial $R(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ with rational coefficents such that $P/Q=R$

Comment: It's true for the case $n=1$.

Comment: Would considering the multivariate polynomials with integer coefficients with $n$ variables as polynomial rings over the ring of multivariate polynomial with integer coefficients and with $n - 1$ variables help?

Comment: Because then you could use induction to prove it to be true for all natural numbers $n$, or false if you find a counterexample at some $n$.

Comment: I believe that the restriction that $R$ has rational coefficients can be further reduced to the restriction that $R$ has integer coefficients as well.

Comment: @Sam As written, this is trivially true: because $P$ and $Q$ have the same number of variables $n$, which means that the only polynomial functions $R$ which would make this true is if $R$ is a constant integer function, which is a multivariate polynomial with rational coefficients.